# Is it possible to customize the color of a UIMenuController?

Tags: iphone, uimenucontroller

The default background color is black. How can I change the color, similar to `tintColor` for navigation bars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible. You may be able to work something out if you subclass it.

EDIT: I took a look at the UIMenuController.h file and there don't seem to be any obvious ways to change the color. It is a subclass of NSObject if that helps you. Also, if you take a look at how people subclass UITabBarController to change it's color you may be able to work out a similar solution.

Comment: It's a singleton, returning only the `sharedMenuController`, so I can't subclass it. Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: It’s not helpful but you can use UIAppearance to change UIButton's background color. From there the rounded corners are lost. I think this might be modifiable if the layer is changed but I don’t see a way to access that.

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution to change the **text color** consists in using the appearance proxy of the UIButton inside the UIMenuController. The thing is it uses directly the private UIButton subclass used by Apple in the Menu Controller. I would never recommend to access a private Apple class (and furthermore through its name), but in that specific Menu Controller color customization case I think that's the best solution. It lets you define the clean way your view appearances.

**Swift**

```
(NSClassFromString("UICalloutBarButton")! as! UIButton.Type).appearance().setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

**Objective-C**

```
[[NSClassFromString(@"UICalloutBarButton") appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Has anyone ever used this while passing App Store Review?

Comment: @shallowThought Yes and it passed

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of UIMenuController like this -

**Objective-C**

```
[[NSClassFromString(@"UICalloutBarButton") appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.8]];
```

Make sure that you use a color with transparency/alpha, otherwise it will throw an error.