# Text color in UIMenuController affected by UIButton appearance setting

Tags: uibutton, uiappearance, uimenucontroller

### I've observed following:

By setting the *Titlecolor* of a `UIButton` with appearance, the `UIMenuItems` in a `UIMenuController` of a `UITextView` are getting the same color.

#### Code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
[[UIButton appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

### My question:

Is there a way to suppress it
**or**
give a `UIMenuItems` another color?

### What i have tried:

1. With appearanceWhenContainedIn `UITextview`
   I've tried to set the appearance for buttons contained in TextViews with
   `[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITextView class], nil]`
   But this obviously didn't work since the `UIMenuController` is not inside the TextView.
2. With appearanceWhenContainedIn `UIMenuController/UIMenuItem`
   Is not possible, since both are not implementing the UIAppearanceContainer protocol.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466570/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-color-of-a-uimenucontroller

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Have you discovered a solution?

Comment: No i could not fix it. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found 2 ways to fix this issue.

Here is a screenshot of the result of the following solutions :

[image]

### **First solution**

The UIMenuController is not contained in the View Controller views hierarchy. You can thus define your UIButton color that way (**instead of** setting the global Button *appearance*) :

**Swift :**

```
UIButton.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UIViewController.self]).setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

**Objective-C :**

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[UIViewController.class]] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

That solution works for most of the cases. But if you use the **delete button** or actions button of **Table View Cells** it will also take the set color and you **won't be able to change that color** through appearance proxy.

### **Second solution (my preferred one)**

The second solution uses directly the **private UIButton subclass** class name used by Apple in the Menu Controller.
I would never recommend to access a private Apple class (and furthermore through its name), but in that specific Menu Controller color customization case I think that's the best solution. It lets you define the clean way your view appearances.

**Swift :**

Define your global Button title color appearance :

```
UIButton.appearance().setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Specific exception for the MenuController :

```
(NSClassFromString("UICalloutBarButton")! as! UIButton.Type).appearance().setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

**Objective-C :**

*Define your global Button title color appearance :*

```
[[UIButton appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

*Specific exception for the MenuController :*

```
[[NSClassFromString(@"UICalloutBarButton") appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: `UIButton.appearance().setTitleColor` doesn't seem valid code